# Error at lib support appcompat_v7

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

I am having trouble to at library appcompat_v7

It have error on path

> res/values-v21/styles_base.xml

and at line 75 show error - below 75 to 78:

> ```
> <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"
>           parent="android:Widget.Material.ActionButton">
>  </style>
> ```

at console:

> home/user/workspace/appcompat_v7/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:156: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.

and several error similares changing just the 'android:*'

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have the same problem here. Looks like it's a problem with the API v21 update

Comment: Did you try using the new SDK of API level 21?

Comment: I finally made my app running by switching to API level 21 for my app as well as the appcompat project/module (i.e. the project that includes the resources used by compatibility lib v21). Now I found out, that v21 doesn't seem to include the holo theme and my app looks totally different :(

Comment: So I recovered appcompat-v7 resources from "Android Support Repository" by extracting from `appcompat-v7-20.0.0.aar` and getting android-support-v7-appcompat.jar from my git repo. Now it's running again with the style it had before the update.

Comment: @RaulPinto, Yes, I am compiling with the API 21.

Comment: @RaulPinto, Did you solved the issue? If you did, could you answer the question making a step-by-step how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I'm not sure, if this a real "solution" but here is my theory and what I did:

## My Theory

After updating the "Android Support Library" version 21, I got a similar error. It seems, my IntelliJ didn't update the resources in my module correctly, which pointed to the ressources directory for appcompat.

Furthermore, I had some widgets and Code that directly pointed to drawables in those ressources.

But in v21 of the Android Support Library Google dropped **support for the Holo theme**!

Hence, the compiler complains about not finding the resources my theme depends on.

## What I did

### When it compiled

To be honest, I'm not really sure in how I came out making this work. I guess, I used did some restarting and cache emptying etc. Copying ressources to my project's folder etc. When my app finally started, it looked different! Of course, it had the *Material* theme instead of the *Holo* theme.

And not everything survived this transition. E.g. the Action Bar was black (standard) instead of green (my theme). So I tried to go back to an old version of appcompat instead of migrating my whole app to Material.

Since you asked me for my solution, I'm posting what I did to "downgrade" to appcompat v20.

### Downgrading to appcompat v20

1. Start SDK Manager
2. Download *Android Support Repository*
3. Go to directory \android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7\20.0.0\ where Android SDK is installed
4. Extract all files from `appcompat-v7-20.0.0.aar` (it's a zip file) to `libs\appcompat\` directory in my project, after I created the directory `appcompat`
5. Added these as a module in my IntelliJ and made my project depend on this module
6. Recovered `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` for v20 from my git repository
7. Used the recovered appcompat jar instead of the v21 one

Step 6 is the one, I found very difficult. I expected the `classes.jar` from the .aar file to be the `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar`, but it wasn't. I even don't know, where you can get the `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` from in the right version because I didn't find it in the repository. And I didn't want to download it from "somewhere in the internet".

I was "lucky", it already was in my git in the correct version.

Now my app compiled and looked correctly. Hope so does yours!

Comment: I was not so lucky to have it already in my git repo; and the sdk updater deleted it from the file system.  What I did in the end: git clone from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1, git checkout to that tag (cae6ca....) and then have Eclipse import the v7 folder as a project

Comment: So, for my part, I had to checkout Branch android-support-lib-19.1.0 from the git repository (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/android-support-lib-19.1.0), because otherwise my app didn't run under Android 2.3.4 (API Level 10).

Comment: You can download v20 support lib here: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r20.zip

Then follow the steps here: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Follow the 'Adding libraries with resources' guide.

Answer (score 4):

Had same problem after upgrading my Eclipse and import "Android Support Library" in workspace.

I think it's a bad solution to "Downgrading to appcompat" so I tried to find another way and found it.
My problem was that my "Project Build Target" of AppCompat was set to API lvl 19. So this is a problem:

> -Eclipse wasn't load the data for API lvl 21 for AppCompat.
>
> -Appcompat have Target API lvl 19, but trying to set style for API lvl 21.

Maybe You have same problem so checkout what was help me:

1.

> Right click on Appcompat project => Properties => Android => Checkout where was your mark, and if it's not set on Android 5.0 - fix it and click ok.

2.

> Project => Clean => Set "Clean all projects" => Ok

P.S. Sorry if I have mistakes - English isn't my native language.

Answer (score 3):

> home/user/workspace/appcompat_v7/res/*values-v21*/themes_base.xml:156: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.

I assumed `values-v21` stands for api level 21, so I updated to android 5.0 and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is more radical:
delete all styles files and every reference for them

Comment: Welcome to SO. With all detailed and relevant answers there, I would suggest you to spend some more time explain why and how this is better approach than others above. Thanks.