# Install Eclipse ADT bundle: error appeared in project library "appcompat_v7"

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to android development. I have downloaded the Eclipse ADT bundle after 20th of October from developer.android.com. I followed the instructions and finished the installation. When I open Eclipse, it automatically appeared a project named "appcompat_V7" with a red "x" on it.

Explored the "res/values_v21/" I can found that the red "x" appeared on the file styles_base.xml".

A long list of error is shown in the console tab. The error messages are similar so that I just paste the first error here:

`C:\AndroidDev\MyWorkSpace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.`

I have already tried the solution provided on 
"[Error at lib support appcompat_v7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453942/error-at-lib-support-appcompat-v7)" and
"[error after updating the support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436283/error-after-updating-the-support-library)". Unfortunately, still not work.

Any ideas of how to fix the problem?

Comment: What are the min and target versions in the appcombat_v7 manifest?

Comment: try to add support library

Comment: Here are the min and target versions I found in appcombat_v7 AndroidManifest.xml <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>